# Is Google reCAPTCHA a tool to make a two-factor authentication?

Tags: recaptcha, captcha, two-factor-authentication

I've been reading about two-factor authentication, as I'll need to build it on my next project (how we'll build is not defined yet). As I've been researching, I've been wondering if using a captcha mechanism (like Google reCAPTCHA) along with a traditional login-password authentication method would be considered a two-factor authentication process.

Anyone can help me on that? 
Thank you.

Comment: No, not at all. 2FA is when you have another device, or software application, that is a second means of authentication. It gives you a token or a password to use *on top of* your normal password. Captchas are just used for spam control.

Answer (score 4):

When we talk about two-factor authentication two of the following factors are used: knowledge factor, possession factor, and inherence factor. Login-password authentication is the first factor - your password is something you know. As the second factor, you can use a token, an SMS, an email (something you have) or your fingerprints, voice or face scanning (something you are).
CAPTCHA cannot be considered as the second factor. It is used to verify that you are a real person, not a robot.